# select on table dbroom doesn't read item previously inserted in table

Tags: android, select, insert, fragment, android-room

I'm trying to read all the occurs of a table from a Fragment, after an insert. The query read all occurs except the last record previosly inserted . The insert was in one fragment, the select was in another fragment.

Read a table dbroom  with all occur.

```
[SchedaDAO]

@Dao
interface SchedaDAO {

    @Insert
    fun insert(scheda: Scheda)

    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO SCHEDA_TABLE(nome,ripetizioni,id_esercizio, riposo) VALUES (:nome, :ripetizioni, :idesercizio, :riposo)")
    fun insert(nome : String, riposo : String, idesercizio : Long, ripetizioni : String)


    @Update
    fun update(scheda: Scheda)

    @Delete
    fun delete(scheda: Scheda)

    @Query(value = "Delete from scheda_table ")
    fun deleteAllScheda ()

    @Query("DELETE FROM scheda_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun deleteByIdScheda(id: Long)

    @Query("select * FROM scheda_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun selectByIdScheda(id: Long) : Scheda


    @Query("Select * from scheda_table ORDER BY  nome ASC")
    fun getALL()  : List<Scheda>


}
```

```
[EserciziDatabase]


@Database (entities = [Esercizi::class,Scheda::class],  version = 3 , exportSchema = false)
abstract class EserciziDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract  val eserciziDao : EserciziDAO
    abstract  val schedaDAO : SchedaDAO

    companion object  {
       @Volatile
       private  var  INSTANCE : EserciziDatabase? = null

       fun getInstance (context: Context) : EserciziDatabase {
           synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder( context.applicationContext, EserciziDatabase::class.java,
                        "esercizi_database")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                         .createFromAsset("database/esercizi_database.db")
                        .build()


                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
           }
       }
    }
}
```

```
[EserciziViewModel ]

class EserciziViewModel (private val repository: EserciziRepository) : ViewModel() {

    var idesercizio: Int = 0

     fun setidesercizio(str_id_esercizio: Int)  {
        idesercizio = str_id_esercizio
    }
     fun  getidesercizio() = idesercizio

     suspend  fun  myAllEsercizi() : List<Esercizi> = repository.myAllEsercizi()

    suspend fun insert(esercizi: Esercizi)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            repository.insert(esercizi)
        } catch (e : Exception ) {
            Log.e(" errore generico:","valore = ${e}")
            throw java.lang.IllegalStateException("non mi piace questo errore")

        }
    }
    suspend fun update(esercizi: Esercizi)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(esercizi)
    }
     fun delete(esercizi: Esercizi)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(esercizi)
    }
     fun deleteByIdEsercizio(id :Long)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteByIdEsercizio(id)
    }
    suspend fun deleteAllEsercizi()  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteAllEsercizi()
    }


    private val _list = MutableLiveData<List<Scheda>>().apply {
            value = repository.myAllScheda
    }
    val list: LiveData<List<Scheda>> = _list




    //val myAllScheda : LiveData<List<Scheda>> = repository.myAllScheda


    suspend  fun insert(scheda: Scheda)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(scheda)

    }
     fun insertScheda(nome : String, ripetizioni: String , idesercizio : Long, riposo : String)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insertScheda(nome, ripetizioni, idesercizio, riposo)
    }

    suspend  fun update(scheda: Scheda)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(scheda)
    }

     fun delete(scheda: Scheda)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(scheda)
    }
    suspend fun deleteByIdScheda(id :Long)  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteByIdScheda(id)
    }
    suspend fun deleteAllScheda()  = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteAllScheda()
    }
    val _muscolo = MutableLiveData<String>()


     fun setMuscolo(str_muscolo: String) {
        _muscolo.value = str_muscolo
    }
     fun  getmuscolo() = _muscolo


    var esercizio: String = ""
    var ripetizioni: Int = 0
    var riposo: Int = 0


     fun setesercizio(str_esercizio: String) {
        esercizio = str_esercizio
    }
     fun setripetizioni(str_ripetizioni: Int) {
        ripetizioni = str_ripetizioni
    }
     fun setriposo(str_riposo: Int) {
        riposo = str_riposo
    }


     fun  getesercizio() = esercizio
     fun  getripetizioni() =  ripetizioni
     fun  getriposo() = riposo
 }
class EserciziViewModelFactory (private var repository: EserciziRepository)  : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create (modelClass: Class<T>) : T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(EserciziViewModel::class.java)){
            return EserciziViewModel(repository) as T
        }else {
            throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("unkwnon view model")
        }

    }
}
```

[EserciziRepository ]

class EserciziRepository (private  val eserciziDAO: EserciziDAO , private  val schedaDAO: SchedaDAO) {

```
suspend fun  myAllEsercizi () : List<Esercizi>  =  eserciziDAO.getALLEsercizi()

@WorkerThread
suspend fun insert (esercizi: Esercizi) {
    eserciziDAO.insert(Esercizi())
}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun update (esercizi: Esercizi) {
    eserciziDAO.update(Esercizi())
}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun delete (esercizi: Esercizi) {
    eserciziDAO.delete(Esercizi())
}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun deleteAllEsercizi () {
    eserciziDAO.deleteAllEsercizi()
}
@WorkerThread
suspend fun deleteByIdEsercizio (id: Long) {
    eserciziDAO.deleteByIdEsercizio(id)
}
//@WorkerThread
//fun myAllscheda() : List<Scheda> {
// return  schedaDAO.getALL()
//}

val myAllScheda : List<Scheda> = schedaDAO.getALL()

@WorkerThread
suspend fun insert (scheda: Scheda) {
    try {
        schedaDAO.insert(Scheda())
    } catch (e : android.database.SQLException ) {
        Log.e(" repository insert:","valore = ${e}")
        Log.e(" repository insert:","valore = ${e.localizedMessage}")
    throw IllegalStateException("non mi piace questo errore")
    }

}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun update (scheda: Scheda) {
    schedaDAO.update(Scheda())
}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun delete (scheda: Scheda) {
    schedaDAO.delete(Scheda())
}

@WorkerThread
suspend fun deleteAllScheda () {
    schedaDAO.deleteAllScheda()
}
@WorkerThread
suspend fun deleteByIdScheda (id: Long) {
    schedaDAO.deleteByIdScheda(id)
}
@WorkerThread
suspend fun insertScheda (nome: String, ripetizioni: String, idesercizio : Long, riposo : String) {
    schedaDAO.insert(nome, ripetizioni, idesercizio , riposo )
}
```

}

```
[SchedaFragment ]

class SchedaFragment : Fragment() {


  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val ripetizioni : String  = eserciziViewModel!!.getripetizioni().toString()
        val riposo : String  = eserciziViewModel!!.getriposo().toString()
        val idesercizio : Int  = eserciziViewModel!!.getidesercizio().toString().toInt()
        val button = view?.findViewById(R.id.inserisci_text_button) as Button
        val nome_scheda = view?.findViewById(R.id.nomeScheda) as TextView
        button.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                insert(nome_scheda.text.toString(), ripetizioni, riposo, idesercizio)// onResult is called on the main thread
            }

        }
        scheda = eserciziViewModel.list
        Log.i(" vedo dopo insert  :","valore = ${scheda.value}")
    }

    suspend fun insert(str_nome_sch : String, str_ripetizioni : String, str_riposo : String, str_id_esercizio : Int){
        try {

           // eserciziViewModel!!.insert(Scheda(str_nome_sch,str_ripetizioni,str_id_esercizio.toLong(),str_riposo))
            eserciziViewModel!!.insertScheda(str_nome_sch,str_ripetizioni,str_id_esercizio.toLong(),str_riposo)
        } catch (e : Exception ) {

            Log.e(" errore insert :","valore = ${e}")
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), " errore inserimento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }finally {
         Log.i(" occur inserita  :","valore = ${str_nome_sch}")
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), " scheda inserita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
    }
}
```

```
[Fragment_third]

 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        utility.pulisciArray(nome)

        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewS)
        Log.i(" oncreate view :","valore = ${view}")
        Log.i(" third fragment :","valore = ${view}")


        val data: MutableList<HashMap<String, String>> = mutableListOf()
        scheda = eserciziViewModel.list

        // legge DB
        //eserciziViewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        eserciziViewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {scheda
            Log.i(" scheda variATA:","valore = ${scheda.value}")
           scheda.let {    Log.i("scheda variata :","valore = ${it}")

         }
        })
```